# Determine the number of strikes in a random number, depending on user's input

Tags: c, function, random

The function "strike" has to return the number of times that the user's input are equivalent.

> Assume, the random number is 1234.
>
> if the user's input has one of the random's numbers, then strike1++.
>
> e.g., if my input is 5152  then strike1 will be 2.
>
> if my input is, 1112, then strike will be again 2.

I'm getting wrong output in strike1. Any ideas how to solve it?
(I don't want to solve it with arrays)

**Solution:**

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int hit(int num);
int strike(int num);
int rndNum(int num);

void main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int chosenNum;
    int saveHits, saveStrikes;
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("The Random number: %d", chosenNum = rndNum(num));
    printf("\nPlease enter a 4 digit number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    saveHits = hit(num, chosenNum);
    saveStrikes = strike(num, chosenNum);
    printf("\nThe number of hits: %d", saveHits);
    printf("\nThe number of strikes: %d", saveStrikes);
    getch();
}
int rndNum(int num)
{
    int rndNum = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
    
    return rndNum;
}

int hit(int num1, int chosenNum1)
{
    int i, hit1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
            if (num1 % 10 == chosenNum1 % 10)
                hit1++;
            num1 /= 10;
            chosenNum1 /= 10;
    }
    return hit1;
}

int strike(int num1, int chosenNum1)
{
    int i, strike1 = 0, n = 1;
    int temp = num1, temp2 = chosenNum1;
    for (i = 0;i < 4;i++)
    {
        while (n > 0)
        {
            if (temp > 0)
            {
                if ((temp % 10 == temp2 % 10))
                {
                    strike1++; n--;
                }
                else
                    temp /= 10;
            }
            else
                n--;
        }
        temp2 /= 10;
        n = 1;
        temp = num1;
    }
    return strike1;
}
```

Comment: hey guys, solved it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int strike(int num1, int chosenNum1)
{
    int i, strike1 = 0, n = 1;
    int temp = num1, temp2 = chosenNum1;
    for (i = 0;i < 4;i++)
    {
        while (n > 0)
        {
            if (temp > 0)
            {
                if ((temp % 10 == temp2 % 10))
                {
                    strike1++; n--;
                }
                else
                    temp /= 10;
            }
            else
                n--;
        }
        temp2 /= 10;
        n = 1;
        temp = num1;
    }
    return strike1;
}
```